Pauli matrix exponentials
Just a short query to confirm my understanding.
Given the Pauli-X operator $\hat{X}$ and it's eigenstates $|+\rangle:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)$ and $|-\rangle:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle - |1\rangle)$. If we consider the matrix exponential $e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}\hat{X}}$, am I correct that it follows that $e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}\hat{X}}|+\rangle = e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}}|+\rangle$ and $e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}\hat{X}}|-\rangle = e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}|-\rangle$ since $\hat{X}|+\rangle = |+\rangle$ and $\hat{X}|-\rangle = -|-\rangle$?
This is motivated by the result that:
For eigenvectors $|\lambda \rangle$ of $\hat{A}$ we have $e^{\hat{A}\theta}|\lambda \rangle = e^{\lambda \theta}|\lambda \rangle$.

Yes. This same question was asked (for Hamiltonians) a few days ago.


am I correct that it follows that $e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}\hat{X}}|+\rangle = e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}}|+\rangle$ and $e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}\hat{X}}|-\rangle = e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}|-\rangle$ since $\hat{X}|+\rangle = |+\rangle$ and $\hat{X}|-\rangle = -|-\rangle$?

Yes.
You can, for example, consider the Taylor series expansion to understand this result:
$$
e^{-i\frac{\theta}{2}\hat X} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}{\left(-i\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}^n \hat X^n
$$
For example, every power of $\hat X^n$ acting on $|+\rangle$ gives $(1)^n|+\rangle = |+\rangle$.
